# default JPanel in JFrame is smaller

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

When I add a `JPanel` inside a `JFrame` of size (640,480), the `JPanel` has a size of (638
449). I need the `JPanel` to match the `JFrame` exactly!

A temporary work-around I found is to `setUndecorated` on the `JFrame` to true. It seems the `JFrame` takes pixels away for the menu-bar and the border around the window.

Comment: Unless the frame is undecorated, it's impossible for the panel to match the exact size of the frame, as the frame has a border and title bar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the size of the frame. Instead your code should be:

```
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Then the panel will be displayed at its `preferred size` and the frame can still have its decorations. So this means you need to set the panels preferred size not its size.

Or the preferred approach is to override the `getPreferredSize()` method  of the panel if you need the panel to have a specific size.

Comment: can't accept answer yet, but that saved me a lot of time, thx!

Comment: @Vjeetje This is the correct answer. Setting undecorated will also do _exactly_ what you asking for but basically you shouldn't try to do that in Swing. You would be going against a very fundamental functionality of Swing (layouts). You didn't say why you need them to be the same size but if it's because you are using the dimensions for something, just only use the panel. If you really need them to be the same size specifically then setting undecorated is the only way but that is inconvenient for obvious reasons.